# How to find appropriate entry for a pom online?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to find an appropriate `pom` entry for

```
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
```

Got to web, but nothing further

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Ultimately i need to import

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

But am unable to locate this jar in [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/). Found everything i needed but servlet.

Please assist

Comment: Have you tried adding `spring-web` as dependency to your project ?

Comment: `spring-web` artifact is added as a dependency as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required class is in `spring-webmvc`, seen [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-webmvc%22).

The website [www.findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com) is very useful for finding jars containing particular classes.

Comment: Thank you! In this example, how did you know that artifact id is `spring-webmvc`?

Comment: Just do a search on findJAR for the fully-qualified class name and you'll get a list of all the matching jars. For example, [ModelAndView](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html). Then you can search for the matching jar on Maven Central if you need to confirm the artefact ID.